# Redirecting to salesforce record type selection page from visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, record-type, urlhacking, page-override

I am overriding the New button of a custom object using a Visualforce page. Now this vf page's controller does some calculation based on a criteria and assigns a record type to the newly created custom object, save the custom object and redirects the user to the newly created record.

However if the criteria is not met I want to send the user to the standard record type selection page, where they will select a record type and it will redirect them back to this same page where the code will read the selected record type, create a new record and then redirect the users to the new record page.

I am successfully able to redirect the user to the standard record type selection page using this url :

```
/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?retURL=%2Fa0G%2Fo&ent=01Ii0000000mXbK
```

However after selecting the record type I am not able to redirect them back to the vf page with the selected record type id.

I figured I needed the save_new_url parameter or I updated the link to

```
/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?retURL=%2Fa0G%2Fo&ent=01Ii0000000mXbK&save_new_url=/apex/MyVfPage
```

But its still not working.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you instead just allow them to select the record type on your visualforce page?

Comment: I can, but that is not what the "requirements" want me to do. They want the user to be redirected to the standard record type selection page.

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you see when the redirection happens, but when I try the same in my dev org, it **does redirect** to the VF page from the record type selection page and the **selected record type id** comes in as a **query string parameter**.

here's the url in the record type selection page

```
https://{mySFDomain}/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Case&retURL=%2F500%2Fo&retURL%3D%252F500%252Fo&save_new_url=/apex/hello
```

and when i select a record type and click continue, i end up with this url

```
https://{myVFDomain}/apex/hello?RecordType=012900000015G4p&ent=Case&retURL%3D%252F500%252Fo
```

Note : I have used Case object in my dev org.. and don't think it will behave different for a custom object, so this should work for you as well.